# Setting a variable to a certain value or default to all values in a column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Sorry if my heading is very clear. I am trying to create a stored procedure :

```
Create Procedure Pro1 @a nvarchar = null, @b nvarchar =null
as
Select * from table1
where Parameter1 = '1'
and Parameter2 = @a
go
```

Above is not the actual code but i  hope it explains what i am trying to achieve. I am selecting on two parameters. 'Parameter2'  depends on the variable @a. The challenge i have is that if @a remains null at execution; i want the select statement to search on all values of Parmeter2 as if the 'and' statement was not there. I could write a if else statement to execute different selects but i was hoping i could simply set @a to some sort
of wildcard value that would simply do this? Maybe something : 'like []'?

Comment: Simple answer: `AND (Parameter2 = @a OR @a IS NULL)`. If this gets overly complex, you may find better performance using dynamic SQL to build up the statement with only the clauses that are relevant.

Comment: Also, [STOP DECLARING VARIABLE-LENGTH DATA TYPES WITHOUT LENGTH](https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length.aspx). Sorry to yell but I don't understand why so many people are so lazy about this.

Comment: Actually in the code i have lengths included, i just forgot to include them in this example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.Pro1 -- use schema prefix when creating objects!
  @a NVARCHAR(32) = NULL -- 32 should match data type of Parameter2 column
AS
BEGIN -- wrap your body and indent for readability
  SET NOCOUNT ON; -- should always turn off DONE_IN_PROC messages

  SELECT columns -- please name your columns instead of SELECT *
    FROM dbo.table1 -- use schema prefix when referencing objects
    WHERE (Parameter2 = @a OR @a IS NULL); -- semi-colons please!
END
GO
```

In some cases you may find that if you have a lot of these optional parameters, SQL Server will compile a plan for one set of parameters and that plan will not be very beneficial for different parameters. So you may want something like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.Pro1
  @a NVARCHAR(32) = NULL
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

  SET @sql = N'SELECT columns FROM dbo.table1 WHERE 1=1';

  IF @a IS NOT NULL
    SET @sql += ' AND Parameter2 = @a';

  EXEC sp_executesql @sql,
    N'@a NVARCHAR(32)',
    @a;
END
GO
```